# How can I add scrollbars to a widget with painted lines?

Tags: python, scroll, widget, pyqt, drawing

I am having trouble getting this to work the way I want. I want to draw a number of lines below each other and display this in a window that has scrollbars.

So far I can draw the lines and display them, but my scrollbars wont work. What is the correct way to do this?

The file y.list contains simple pairs of numbers as start and end point of my lines. Like:

```
1 100
4 64
72 98
```

Here is my code so far:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()         

    def paintEvent(self, e):

        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        self.drawLines(qp)
        qp.end()

    def drawLines(self, qp):

        wTotal = 4*2*117

        pen = QPen(QColor(100, 200, 0), 5, Qt.SolidLine)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawLine(24, 20, 24+wTotal, 20)

        pen = QPen(QColor(0, 0, 255), 2, Qt.SolidLine)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawLine(24+wTotal/2,18,24+wTotal/2,22)

        pen = QPen(QColor(0, 50, 255), 2, Qt.SolidLine)
        qp.setPen(pen)

        with open("y.list", 'r') as points:

            linecount = 0
            for line in points:

                linecount += 1
                splitLine = line.split()

                start = int(splitLine[0])*4
                end = int(splitLine[1])*4

                qp.drawLine(20+start, 20+5*linecount, 20+end, 20+5*linecount)


class Widget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent= None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()

        self.setGeometry(200,100,1100,800)
        #Container Widget        
        widget = QWidget()
        #Layout of Container Widget
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lines = Example()
        layout.addWidget(lines)
        widget.setLayout(layout)

        #Scroll Area Properties
        scroll = QScrollArea()
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scroll.setWidget(widget)

        #Scroll Area Layer add 
        vLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vLayout.addWidget(scroll)
        self.setLayout(vLayout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    dialog = Widget()
    dialog.show()

    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you have made the widget resizable, so the widget will be automatically resized to fit the available space, and the scrollbars will never change (because they're not needed).

To change this, you need give the widget a specific size, and don't automatically resize it:

```
    scroll.setWidgetResizable(False)
    scroll.setWidget(widget)
    widget.resize(2000, 2000)
```

NB: don't attempt to programmatically resize the widget during the paint-event, because resizing can itself cause a re-paint.

Comment: Wow such a simple solution, I swear I tried something like this but must have missed the correct order or sth. Anyway, thanks! :)